# AnimatableData not working in Shape object with SwiftUI

Tags: path, swiftui

I have this Shape object (Curve) that I'm trying to animate:

```
private struct Curve : Shape {
    private var startAngle : CGFloat
    private var endAngle : CGFloat
    private var drawn : Bool
    private var hAdjustment : CGFloat
    
    var clockwise : Bool = true
    
    init(side: CurveSide, isDrawn: Bool) {
        self.startAngle = side.startAngle
        self.endAngle = side.endAngle
        self.hAdjustment = side == .left ? 25 : -25
        self.drawn = isDrawn
    }
    
    var animatableData : CGFloat {
        get { self.endAngle }
        set { self.endAngle = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let rotationAdjusment = CGFloat(90.0)
        var baseCirclePath = Path()
        baseCirclePath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + CGFloat(self.hAdjustment), y: rect.midY),
                              radius: rect.width / 2.3,
                              startAngle: self.drawn ? Angle(degrees: Double(self.startAngle - rotationAdjusment)) : Angle(degrees: 0),
                              endAngle: self.drawn ? Angle(degrees: Double(self.endAngle - rotationAdjusment)) : Angle(degrees: 0),
                              clockwise: !self.clockwise)
        return baseCirclePath
    }
}
```

This is my contentView where I'm trying to use that shape (Curve):

```
HStack {
       Spacer()
       Curve(side: CurveSide.left, isDrawn: self.leftCurveDrawn)
             .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
             .frame(width: 100)
       Curve(side: CurveSide.right, isDrawn: self.rightCurveDrawn)
             .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
             .frame(width:100)
       Spacer()
       }
```

And I'm using these variables to trigger the animation:

```
 @State private var rightCurveDrawn = true
 @State private var leftCurveDrawn = true
```

And this is what I get int the screen. The problem is that every time I toggle the @State variables the curves only appear and disappear with no animation. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `trim` your shapes and specify animation. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (on replicated code)

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rightCurveDrawn = false
    @State private var leftCurveDrawn = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Curve(side: CurveSide.left, isDrawn: self.leftCurveDrawn)
                .trim(from: 0, to: leftCurveDrawn ? 1 : 0)       // << here !!
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                .frame(width: 100)
            Curve(side: CurveSide.right, isDrawn: self.rightCurveDrawn)
                .trim(from: 0, to: rightCurveDrawn ? 1 : 0)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
                .frame(width:100)
            Spacer()
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))    // << here !!
        .onAppear {
            self.rightCurveDrawn = true     // can be on button or other
            self.leftCurveDrawn = true      // action
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will have to implement animation values yourself. What fun!

To get you started, you could add something like this inside your shape:

```
private var multiplier = 1.0
var animatableData: CGFloat {
    get { CGFloat(self.multiplier) }
    set { self.multiplier = Double(newValue) }
}
```

`multiplier` is nothing special, it's a value added by us, the devs. `animatableData` however, that's SwiftUI magic. By wrapping your state changes in a `withAnimation` closure, it will immediately set your shape to the new values, evaluate the final result of animatableData, and then interpolate the values across the animation time.

We can use the multiplier set in animatableData like so:

```
    baseCirclePath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + CGFloat(self.hAdjustment), y: rect.midY),
                          radius: rect.width / 2.3,
                          startAngle: Angle(degrees: Double(self.startAngle - rotationAdjusment) * self.multiplier),
                          endAngle: Angle(degrees: Double(self.endAngle - rotationAdjusment) * self.multiplier),
                          clockwise: !self.clockwise)
```

And don't forget to add this to the end of your init statement, to give SwiftUI something to evaluate:

```
self.multiplier = self.drawn ? 1 : 0
```

---

### Note

Please note though, that my simple implementation of `animatableData` may not be the kind of animation you want here, but you can customize it however you want.

Finally, here's where I learned everything I know about this [particular problem](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/animating-simple-shapes-with-animatabledata).